# Unrecognized Config Parameter "bytea_output" pgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to connect pgAdmin Version 4 to an existing Postgres instance. Previously I was using pgAdmin 3 and it was working fine. I'm not sure what I might be doing wrong.  I have the following configurations:

[image]

Not sure what I could be missing.

I get the error below:

> Unable to connect to server:
>
> ERROR: unrecognized configuration parameter "bytea_output"

Comment: What is your Postgres version?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Its version 8.4

Comment: I guess pgAdmin 4 simply doesn't support such an outdated (and unsupported) version. `bytea_output` was introduced in 9.0 (which is also no longer maintained)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

PostgreSQL 9.0 and earlier are not supported by pgAdmin 4.

Unfortunately that is not documented yet, but you can find it in [this](https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/1660) and [this](https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/1355) bug report (requires a PostgreSQL community account):

> Sorry, we're only building support for 9.1 and later (the currently supported releases).
>   pgAdmin 3 can still be used with earlier versions.

Comment: please support postgresql shipped with centos 6.x. maybe there is a workaround?

Comment: If you want that request to reach the authors of pgAdmin, you should direct it to the [support mailing list](https://www.pgadmin.org/support/list.php).

Answer (score 3):

pgAdmin4 supports Postgres9.2 & above version.