# PgAdmin4 Error : unrecognized configuration parameter "bytea_output"

Tags: php, ruby, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am using postgresql 9.6 and pgAdmin 4. I want to connect remote database in pgAdmin but getting this error. I have done my R&d but get two things to add in my config file.

> listen_addresses = '*'
>
> host    all all 0.0.0.0/0     md5.

Done these both lines but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

pgAdmin4 do not support PG9.1, it supports PG9.2 & onwards

Comment: Sorry, its 9.6, i am updating my question

Comment: Could you provide more details like OS, pgAdmin4 version, steps to re-produce the issue.

Comment: This question resembles my question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40212212/unrecognized-config-parameter-bytea-output-pgadmin-4

Comment: @MahaDev The given issue was specific to version below PG9.2, But you said you are using PG9.6 that's why I asked for steps.